# grep only whole word partially matching the pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I have log file containing texts starting with "skylabs/plat-". I want to extract whole word matching above text

example text

```
This is a log line 1 skylabs/plat-abcd_1234 end of line
Some other text skylabs/plat-efgj_1234 this is okay
Firth phase of skylabs/plat-lmno-1234-sst all set
Nothing special skylabs/plat-usiu-sku-1234 , good to go
```

I tried

```
egrep -Eo "^(skylabs/plat-)" Text.log
```

but I am not getting anything . i would like to get output similar to below

```
skylabs/plat-abcd_1234 
skylabs/plat-lmno-1234-sst
```

Comment: Is the interpretation of `^` the usual one, with `egrep -Eo`?

Comment: yes , both grep and egrep dosent return anything with ^

Comment: that was a typo. even egrep -Eo "^(skylabs/plat-)" Text.log dosent return any match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$ grep -io 'skylabs/plat[a-z0-9_-]*' Text.log 
skylabs/plat-abcd_1234
skylabs/plat-efgj_1234
skylabs/plat-lmno-1234-sst
skylabs/plat-usiu-sku-1234
```

- `[a-z0-9_-]*` means zero or more of alphabets, numbers, underscore and hyphen (the `i` option is for ignoring case, i.e match both lower/upper case alphabets)

For given input, you can also use `grep -o 'skylabs/plat[^ ]*'` where `[^ ]*` will match zero or more non-space characters. It all depends on what sort of characters you need to match

Notes on `egrep -Eo "^(skylabs/plat-)"`

- `egrep` is exactly same as `grep -E` as far as I know

  - For GNU grep, see [BRE vs ERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended)
- `^` is a metacharacter that will force the match to happen at start of line. Shouldn't be used here
- `()` grouping is unnecessary here
- regex is incomplete after `-`